# DateDiff every 3 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to know if you know how to date diff every 3 days im doing scheduler.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CLAIM_NO,
    ModifiedBy,
    ClaimType,
    ClaimStatus,
    EmailAddress,
FROM EP_ADMIN_ITEM_REMINDER
WHERE Status = 1 AND DATEDIFF(Day,DateAdded,getdate()) = 3
```

This is my code in DATEDIFF i put into WHERE Clause
I have 2 columns for date 1st DateAdded 2nd DateSent. I need to schedule my thing every 3 days so it will update the datesent first and it will check if the datesent is Greterthan the dateadded into 3. I just want to know if my `WHERE` clause is correct. thanks

Comment: If you want Greater Than, why are you using Equals in your comparison?

Comment: noo sorry sorry my mistake.. typo error.. :) ..

Comment: [DATEDIFF Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Although in this simple model (when the reminder happens after 3 days) it seems simple to calculate, in this case I'd advocate storing a Reminder date, or similar. The code to spot due reminders is easier (is it in the past and not yet dealt with?), and if, later, different items need *different* reminder periods, it's easier to modify the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
CLAIM_NO,
ModifiedBy,
ClaimType,
ClaimStatus,
EmailAddress,
FROM EP_ADMIN_ITEM_REMINDER
WHERE Status = 1 AND DATEDIFF(Day,DateAdded,getdate()) > 2
```

Comment: @JayarTanBaldoza so that if you miss a day, for some reason, you don't miss all the things that were supposed to be done that day.

Answer (score 2):

Keep SARGability in mind. Specifically, running a function like you have can degrade performance (I don't remember if DATEDIFF is optimized for this or not) because it has to run it for every row. Try

```
WHERE [DateAdded] > DATEADD(day, -3, getdate())
```